# best way to use a Singleton in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, utilization

Assuming that we have a thread safe singleton class in Java, which would be the best or better way to use it. For instance, consider that we have a Singleton class as:

```
public class MySingleTon {
   // my thread-safe code goes here
}
```

And we have a service class that uses the above singleton in the two possible ways as follows :

1:

```
public class MyService {
   MySingleton singleton;

   public void myMethod1() {
      singleton  = MySingleton.getInstance();
      // code ...
   }

   public void myMethod2() {
      singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();
      // code...
   }
   public void myMethod3() {
      singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();
      // code...
   }
}
```

or

2:

```
public class MyService {

   public void myMethod1() {
      MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();
      // code ...
   }

   public void myMethod2() {
      MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();
      // code...
   }
   public void myMethod3() {
      MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();
      // code...
   }
}
```

In case one the singleton is referenced via an instance variable and in case 2, the singleton is referenced as a method local variable. Considering that both the above snippets are used in multi-threaded environment, which is a better option and why?

Comment: This question is very broad since we don't know any details about your singleton and how exactly are you going to use it. For instance: Is singleton instance mutable, are `myMethod`s going to change state of singleton, can they be synchronized?

Comment: When I say that it's thread-safe (immutable or mutable with synchronized access to mutable state), doesn't it covers all the cases? Not that I am undermining your question here, but just wondering if I missed anything here.

Comment: I mean even if some class is considered thread-safe we can still use it in non-thread safe way, for instance `method1` can set its own state of singleton and do some other things based on assumption that this state stays. But in the same time `method2` can try to change this state to something else. Would it be problem in your case? Would it be possible?

Comment: My singleton has a reference to another stateless class which opens a transaction (TitanTransaction) to a titan graph database.

Comment: @JohnVint said, "...no difference in thread-safety".  The most dubious case is your example 2 because you allow different threads to update the `singleton` variable.  But even that case is completely safe because the threads always update it with the same object reference.  Java guarantees that when a thread reads a reference variable, it will always see a value that was stored at some previous time by the program, and since there's only one value that is ever stored...  You do the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define it a third way

```
public class MyService {
   final static MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.getInstance();

   public void myMethod1() {
      // code ...
   }

   public void myMethod2() {
      // code...
   }
   public void myMethod3() {
      // code...
   }
}
```

In all cases there is no difference in thread-safety

Comment: could even be a constant IMHO

Comment: Yup, could be static.

Answer (score 0):

2 would be better in my opinion.  It gives `MySingleton` freedom to kill the singleton instance and recreate if needed (i.e., self-detecting deadlock or resource contention mitigation).

Comment: Are there any chances of deadlock in the first case??

Comment: If there are no bugs in the thread-safe code, then no.  But, that's a big if.

Comment: I totally agree. Really a big if. :)